# How to add File attachment in campaign Form in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

My CRM is configured in outlook  , and i need to add File attachment in campaign form , I tried Customize->Form... But i cant find File attachment in Field Explorer..

[image]

So how to add this, as shown in image...

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen shot looks like a custom development that isnt a standard control. That said you will probably achieve what you want by just adding the notes grid to your form. A note can have attachments and has a standard file explorer.

Go back into customising the form, click the insert tab on the ribbon, click notes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In CRM Dynamics 2011 there is no control for file explorer. You have to add a control like that through a Webresource (HTML5 or Silverlight) or Iframe that points for an aspx page.

Comment: thanks@Pedro , did u know any web resource link for download?

Comment: Try see this [article](http://microsoftdynamicss.blogspot.pt/2013/01/file-upload-and-download-in-crm-2011.html)

Answer (score 0):

It’s not that hard to knock something up in Silverlight. The annotation entity is just a normal entity and can be written to just like any other. Here is a screen shot of it integrated into a normal CRM form. The control allows you to drag and drop files or click the upload button to be presented with a file dialog box

[image: Screenshot of file uploader]

Oh and one last helper point, the document is stored in the attribute “DocumentBody” as a base64 encoded string. You can then read that and convert it into a byte array to save to disk etc